# How to create events in javascript in order to send them to objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, prototype

I want to create some events in javascript, but what I want is to be able to use them with jQuery objects because I want to do a framework and it has to be easy to use.

What I want is something like this:

```
function myEvent() {//code here}
$("#myObject").myEvent()
```

And trigger the event there, of course I want to know how to get the object which triggered it because I can't do anything without it.

I think that I might have to extend a prototype, but I'm not sure about that.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean custom methods. Events work differently in JavaScript then what your code is trying to display. You can extend jQuery functions like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  check: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  }
});

// Use the newly created .check() method
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).check();
```

DOCS: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

JoshSpears' answer is perfect. Check also this one, I think you'll find easier to implement (just C&P):

Assuming you have, for example:

```
var myEvent = function(str) {
    alert(str);
};
```

And you want something like:

```
$('div').myEvent('hey guys!');
```

Just implement this:

```
$.fn['myEvent'] = function( options ) {
    return this.each( function() {
        myEvent(options);
    });
};
```

This is just a simplification of the jquery plugin pattern wrapper. Check it out here:
https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/jquery.boilerplate.js